# Visual Studio 2015 (ASP.NET Core) Compilation error Error: Microsoft.DotNet.Common.Targets - An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

When trying to build asp.net core project after changing the project path to the solution. I got the following compilation error in my solution referring  visual studio file at "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Common.Targets"

> Error: An item with the same key has already been added. Key: Data    Namespace.ProjectName   C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Common.Targets  241

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8pVTUXkCFSpdWNpNHN5Y01CRnM/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Delete "project.lock.json" file from project files and rebuild the project again

Comment: What the heck IS that file?

Comment: @PrisonerZERO project.lock.json holds the dependency graph of all the packages that you require in that project.

Comment: Sometimes, I have to clean the solution first, then delete the "project.lock.json" file, as suggested above.

Answer (score 5):

A `dotnet restore --no-cache` can also work. The Visual Studio 2015 tooling is not fully baked yet so you will run into these problems from time to time. I usually run into them when I make major changes to project.json.

Answer (score 1):

None of the previous answer worked for me, here is what did the trick:

1. Delete the `project.lock.json` (not always required)
2. Run `dotnet restore --no-cache`
3. Run `dotnet build` (a build in VS at this point still failed but works on command line

After that, it should build fine in VS.

BTW, if you are using TFS, don't forget to add an `*.lock.json` entry to your `.tfignore` file.